# how do i display change password form with angular

Tags: angular, django-rest-framework, angular-ui-router

halo,
i working on a drf and angular project with forgot password functionality where the user request for a change password link via email, which is working but my issue is that after the link is sent to they user's email, how do i display the form that will allow the user change his/her password passing they generate token & uid params to ensure that the user can change the password
below is my code snippets

#apiView

```
class RequestPasswordResetAPIView(generics.GenericAPIView):
    serializers_class = RequestNewPasswordSerializer

    def post(self, request):
        serializer = self.serializers_class(data=request.data)
        email = request.data['email']
        if CustomUser.objects.filter(email=email).exists():
            user = CustomUser.objects.get(email=email)
            uidb64 = urlsafe_base64_encode(smart_bytes(user.id))
            token = PasswordResetTokenGenerator().make_token(user)
            current_site = get_current_site(request=request).domain
            dRelativeLink = reverse(
                'register:password-reset-confirmed', kwargs={'uidb64': uidb64, 'token': token})
            django_absUrl = 'http://' + current_site + dRelativeLink
            body = 'Hi  Click on the Link below to change your password \n' + django_absUrl
```

###url

```
path('password-reset/<uidb64>/<token>/',
         PasswordTokenAPIView.as_view(), name='password-reset-confirmed'),
```

###password-reset link

```
http://localhost:8000/account/password-reset/Mw/arcyok-59633b395b8746c3bfe2efafd613b033/
```

### angular routing config

```
 getPasswordToken(token, uidb64) {
    const url = `localhost:4200/account/${uidb64}/${token}/update-password`
    return this.httpClient.get(url)
  }
```

the issue is i dont know how to pass the uidb64 & token to the url
when i click this link im redirected to the drf view for this link but what i want is to be redirected to the angular form for changing the password and then then this form will call this

```
http://localhost:8000/account/password-reset/Mw/arcyok-59633b395b8746c3bfe2efafd613b033/
```

pls anyone how can i achieve this ?

Answer (score 0):

<strike>Can you share on which port you're running the angular server. And also the routing config for this particular page. I'm assuming there's something missing in either of these things.</strike>
**UPDATED**:
Try this.

1. Change password-reset-link to this, so that when the user clicks the link the form gets opened.

```
http://localhost:4200/account/password-reset/Mw/arcyok-59633b395b8746c3bfe2efafd613b033/
```

2. When the user submits the form with updated password, you can call this

```
http://localhost:8000/account/password-reset/Mw/arcyok-59633b395b8746c3bfe2efafd613b033/
```

OPTIONAL: You can either configure the route in angular something like this

- `{path: 'account/password-reset/:uid/:token', component: ResetPasswordComponent}`, subcribing to routeparams in password-reset component.
- `{path: 'reset_password',component: ForgotPasswordComponent}`, passing the uid & token as queryparams and subscribing to them in password-reset component.

Comment: I have updated my answer,  hope it works :)

Comment: Glad to hear it :) can you mark it accepted though..